# Meaning of "You're only as good as your word"

Tags: meaning

While I am watching Spider Man animation, there's a part I don't understand. Could you help me, please?

There are the lines and I don't exactly understand the bold parts.

> Power Man: I believe in two things, Spider-Man.
>
> **You're only as good as your word**, and second chances.
>
> **And I wouldn't be much of a friend** if I didn't offer the same to you.

Thank you.

Comment: "You" is often used informally to mean "one" or "a person".  *You can't roller skate in a buffalo herd.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Your [word](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/word)" means your promises. So to be only as good as your word is to say that if you do not keep your promises, then you are a bad person; if you do keep your promises, then you are a good person.

> [not much of](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/not-much-of)
>   not to any appreciable degree or extent

So "I wouldn't be much of a friend" means something like

> I wouldn't be considered to be a true friend

I think you can also interpret it is

> I wouldn't be a very good friend

Comment: Thanks a lot! So it means like this? The powerman believes two things. First, Spider man do keep his word. Second, there is a second chance.    So If he din't give second chance to Spider Man, he(power man) would not be a good friend. Am I right?

Comment: No, not quite. I think Power Man believes two things: 1. He believes that a person is as good as his/her word. 2. He believes in second chances. Number 2. means that he believes in giving people a second chance. So, he does not believe that he would be a true friend if he did not offer Spider-man a second chance. I think this implies that he is giving Spider-man a second chance to let Spider-man prove that he (Spider-man) can keep his promise.

Comment: No problem. For this question, you are encouraged to wait for other answers. But for your past questions, consider giving a [check mark ✔](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to respondents. Good luck!

Comment: I didn't know about the chek mark or other things and now I know. Thanks for the information!